# ScrollView не работает. Android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

ScrollView просто не работает. Получается вот такая штука.
[image: ошибка]

Вот сам xml-код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example1110.sap.diplomtesting.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Материалы"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <!--Row1-->
        <!--Column1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"


            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/campfire26" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Переселение народов"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--column2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/cross32" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Крещение Руси"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row2-->
        <!--Column1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"


            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/queen" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Первые русские князья"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--column2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/small" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Татаро-монгольское иго"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row3-->
        <!--Column1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"


            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/mosque32" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Киевская Русь"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--column2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/hammer26" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Железный век"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row4-->
        <!--Column1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"


            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/queen" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Первые русские князья"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--column2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/small" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Татаро-монгольское иго"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row5-->
        <!--Column1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"


            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/mosque32" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Киевская Русь"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--column2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            style="@style/CardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/hammer26" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Железный век"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


      </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Ошибок не выдает

Comment: Без хаков и костылей нельзя заставить нормально заставить работать 2 вложенных скролящихся контейнера (со скролом в одинаковом направлении).

В вашем случае можно попробовать оставить один только GridView и верхние и нижние вьюхи сделать его элементами, т.е. убрать полностью ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Ваш `layout` в целом не правильно сверстан, даже не вооруженным взглядом можно заметить не состыковки, например в начале вы открываете

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="10">
```

а где его закрываете не известно!? В конце открываете `RelativeLayout`, а внутри пустота, зачем он нужен??? Иными словами у вас проблема вовсе не `ScrollView`. Уберите с родителя `ScrollView`, поменяйте например на `LinearLayout` и поэтапно начните верстать, у вас много не со стыковок!